# C failed to include

Tags: c, include

We need to do some enhancement about a downloaded big package.
Assuming the main folder is like

.../proj

and there is

.../proj/Makefile

that will be used to compile the project.

I have added a new folder

.../proj/feature1/file1.h
   .../proj/feature1/file1.c

file1.c is to include file1.h

so

#include "feature1/file1.h"

Then as the Makefile was executed, it stopped at a command like

gcc -c feature1/file1.c -I. ...

The error message read like it failed to include the file1.h

The same codes CAN be compiled at another instance without triggering errors.
   Both instances are ubuntu 10.04. I wouldn't say they are identical, 
   but should be very similar. Any idea what went wrong ? Thanks.

James

Comment: "The error message read like ..." - why don't you copy/paste the actual error message so there's no confusion?  While you're at it, do the same for the `gcc` command the Makefile invoked.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [the "-I" parameters to gcc](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html#SEC14). If the folder "feature1" is in it and not its parent - it will fail. If its parent is in it - it will succeed.

In your case ("-I.") its the "feature1" that's in the search path, not its parent.

Besides, as others mentioned, since both files are in the same directory, you don't need the directory name in the "`include`" directive.

Comment: The Makefile is at the parent of feature1. And in file1.c it also include "feature2/file2.h" include "feature3/file3.h" ...

Comment: @user462301 I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. Where the make file is is irrelevant, command "gcc -I." is invoked in each directory, and in each directory "." points to current, not to the one where the make file is.

Answer (score 1):

```
file1.c is to include file1.h
```

In this case both of files are in the same folder, so I think it have to be:

```
#include "file1.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the .h and .c files are in the same directory, I would expect the include to be:

```
#include "file1.h"
```